# Mac Ports keeps on re-installing Perl, Python, etc

Tags: macports

Every time I want to install something, mac ports keeps on re-installing Perl, Python, etc. although the same packages are already installed on the system. Is there some setting to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried removing them completely (and their dependencies) and then reinstalling?  What you are seeing is certainly not normal.  I've installed both Python and Perl as dependencies of another package and neither have been updated since.

Comment: What are some of the things you are installing that are causing the repeated installs of Perl, Python, etc...?

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing there are most probably upgrades for your ports. MacPorts will automatically upgrade all dependencies before installing new ports. Check `port outdated` to see a list of available upgrades and `sudo port upgrade outdated` to install them.

It is usually recommended to let MacPorts upgrade dependencies before installing new ports to get the latest fixes. However, if you really need to install a port quickly, you can use `sudo port -n install` to avoid this behavior and just install the new port only.

Answer (score 0):

It also might be worth your while checking out [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). Unlike MacPorts it tries to work with the unix software that comes with your Mac rather than installing alternative versions.